# jQuery Overlay Apple by using <a>?

Tags: jquery, overlay, jquery-tools

regarding [jQuery Tools Apple Overlay demo](http://flowplayer.org/tools/demos/overlay/apple.html)

How do I use text link `<A>` to run the overlay instead of using IMG?

Comment: Have you actually tried anything? Do you want the overlay to contain an image, or a web page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to change the jquery selector to identify your link (or any type of object for that matter).

Change:

```
$("#apple img[rel]").overlay({effect: 'apple'});
```

To:

```
$("#apple_link").overlay({effect: 'apple'});//selects a single link with an id of 'apple_link'
```

or

```
$("a[rel]").overlay({effect: 'apple'});//selects all links with a rel attribute
```

Where 'apple_link' is the id of the link, also add a rel attribute onto the link like so:

```
<a href='#' rel='div_to_open' id='apple_link'>Link Text</a>
```

Note: The value of the rel is the div that will be opened in the overlay

Comment: alrite, this is what i wanted. Thanks !

I am just a newbie to js and jquery. still learning. 

Thanks for the tip !

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean like in [this demo](http://flowplayer.org/tools/demos/overlay/external.html)?

```
$("a[rel]").overlay({

    mask: 'darkred',
    effect: 'apple',

    onBeforeLoad: function() {

    // grab wrapper element inside content
    var wrap = this.getOverlay().find(".contentWrap");

    // load the page specified in the trigger
    wrap.load(this.getTrigger().attr("href"));
    }
});
```

Comment: quite similar, but i want to show a div instead of new page:
My idea was to show a form to submit when the link was clicked. I am not sure if using a new page is better or just use a hidden div within a page.

Comment: Take a look at the other demos. They show you exactly how to do what you want, you just need to combine them appropriately. http://flowplayer.org/tools/demos/overlay/modal-dialog.html

Comment: Thanks ! i could use this method too. highly appreciate your input. :)